# ExtJs doesn't load data to a form

Tags: java, javascript, json, url, extjs4.2

this is my model

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'first',
    mapping : 'name.first'
}, {
    name : 'last',
    mapping : 'name.last'
}, 'company', 'email', {
    name : 'dob',
    type : 'date',
    dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
} ]
```

});

and this is my store

```
var store = Ext
    .create(
            'Ext.data.Store',
            {
                // alert("inside")
                // id: 'store',
                model : 'Contact',
                proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                    url : 'urlForJson',
                    reader : 'json',
                    root : 'contact'
                },
                autoLoad : true
            });
```

and this is my form panel

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title : 'Simple Form with FieldSets',
    labelWidth : 75, 
    // url : 'save-form.php',
    frame : true,
    bodyStyle : 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width : 340,
    bodyPadding : 5,

    layout : 'anchor', // arrange fieldsets side by side
    items : [ {
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        title : 'Contact Information',
        defaultType : 'textfield',
        defaults : {
            width : 280
        },
        items : [ {
            fieldLabel : 'First Name',
            emptyText : 'First Name',
            name : 'first'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Last Name',
            emptyText : 'Last Name',
            name : 'last'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Company',
            name : 'company'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Email',
            name : 'email',
            vtype : 'email'
        }, {
            xtype : 'datefield',
            fieldLabel : 'Date of Birth',
            name : 'dob',
            allowBlank : false,
            maxValue : new Date()
        } ]
    } ],

    buttons : [ {
        text : 'Load',
        handler : function() {
            formPanel.getForm().load({
                url : 'xml-form-data.xml',
                waitMsg : 'Loading...'
            });
        }
    }, {
        text : 'Submit',
        disabled : true,
        formBind : true,
        handler : function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().submit({
                url : 'xml-form-errors.xml',
                submitEmptyText : false,
                waitMsg : 'Saving Data...'
            });
        }
    } ],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
var record = store.getAt(0);
 formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

}

);

but this is not loading the data from the store,
and also when i put this line

'formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);'

it gives me this ERROR as well
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined "
hope that anybody can help me

Answer (score 2):

It seems record is undefined. can you confirm this with `console.log(record)`.

If this is the case see load event:

e.g.

```
var store = Ext.create(
    'Ext.data.Store',
    {
        // alert("inside")
        // id: 'store',
        model : 'Contact',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'urlForJson',
            reader : 'json',
            root : 'contact'
        },
        autoLoad : false,
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records) {
                var record = store.getAt(0);
                formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Then call store.load() after form panel is rendered.
Also ensure formPanel is visible in load event callback.
In case it's not visible add id to the panel and use `Ext.get(formId)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the data store for something that can display only one set of data items at a time.

The problem may be in Json Format too. Json format should contain success property and
data property. Please refer below link for reference

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Action.Load

Answer (score 0):

You should have records in your store preloaded values. You may reach that by store.load() or by declarative autoLoad: true (this way may cause uncovered issue when you newbe in Ext JS Execution flow).

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
formPanel.loadRecord(record);
```